# Unable to write a dataframe to db2. Getting error:An unexpected token "?" was found following "

Tags: python

The objective is to insert my dataframe to the empty dataframe i created and write to the db2. Below are the steps i have done:
I have created an empty data frame as give below:

```
data = []
Open_AR_prediction = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['AGING', 'OPEN_INV_NUM', 'NETDUEDATE'])

    tuple_of_tuples = tuple([tuple(x) for x in subset.values])
    sql = "INSERT INTO AVENT.Open_AR_prediction(?,?,?)"
    stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql)
    ibm_db.execute_many(stmt, tuple_of_tuples)
```

Got the below error while running the above code:

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-bf6ba9ab8c93> in <module>
----> 1 ibm_db.execute_many(stmt, tuple_of_tuples)

 SQLCODE=-104ion: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "?" was found following ".Open_AR_prediction(".  Expected tokens may include:  "<values>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: Can you format you codes please?

Comment: This doesn't execute, you need to edit it to add the missing import statements and assignments that `conn, ibm_db`. Anyway it's objecting to `"INSERT INTO AVENT.Open_AR_prediction(?,?,?)"`, is that legal SQL? or some format placeholder.